# Create a listener when an file has been uploaded to SFTP in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

My current project is based on Spring Integration. I am developing this project by using spring Boot.

My goal is to use Spring Integration to complete the below task.

1.I want to create listener in spring integration, to know when a file has been uploaded to SFTP server.

Well want to get clarity why we use SftpInboundFileSynchronizer?

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SftpConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(sftpHost);
        factory.setPort(sftpPort);
        factory.setUser(sftpUser);
        if (sftpPrivateKey != null) {
            factory.setPrivateKey(sftpPrivateKey);
            factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(privateKeyPassPhrase);
        } else {
            factory.setPassword("sftpPassword");
        }
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>(factory);
    }


@Bean
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer filesynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
        filesynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        filesynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpRemoteDirectoryDownload);
        filesynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(sftpRemoteDirectoryDownloadFilter));
        return filesynchronizer;

    }
```

Well i have refer some stackoverflow post, get some knowledge how to work with spring Integration. As I am new to Spring Integration, is this the correct approach i am going to create a listner and read files?

Please provide some sample code how to create a listener, that will detect when a file has been uploaded to SFTP?

Answer (score 1):

There is events like that to listen from the remote SFTP server. What we suggest so far is a passive polling approach. So, the specific `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` endpoint asks the resource for data with some pre-configured timing trigger. On the other hand that endpoint is supplied with some `MessageSource` implementation, which in case of SFTP is `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` if you are going to rely on the synchronization with the local directory before processing files.

Please, consult more with docs for some clarifications and details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound

Here you can find some samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples